Polygon Pour cutout in repeat design (Multi channel)
I'm using repeated circuit option in Altium to repeat 64 times the same design:

Everything works as it should in the PCB:

Except the Polygon Pour cutout, I made this Polygon Pour cutout in the master room as follows:

Confirm Channel Format Copy:

But when I used the room format option, these Polygon Pour cutouts do not appear in the other rooms, would you please let me know how can I fix this?

Hows is the copy configured? (please share a screenshot of the "Confirm Channel Format Copy" window)

@Attie thank you very much, it is added

... what happens if you check that "Copy All Objects Touching the Room" box, or uncheck the "Exclude NoNet Objects"?

Note that the cutout is probably not associated with the room in any way, so the best option here may just be copy / paste, using a via or pad as an anchor.

@Attie by using this "Copy All Objects Touching the Room" it is fixed, thanks a lot

In the "Confirm Channel Format Copy" window, make sure to check the "Copy All Objects Touching the Room" checkbox.


Thank you very much, maybe would you please also vote on my questions?
